# When changing currently signed users email, I get CREDENTIAL_TOO_OLD_LOGIN_AGAIN

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a user who signs in it with: `signInWithEmailAndPassword` method. Then they go to their profile and want to change their email address with: `updateEmail` method.

However I keep getting error: `CREDENTIAL_TOO_OLD_LOGIN_AGAIN`, which I dont understand, since the user just signed in.

How do I get around it? I dont want them to have to go through a sign in process all over again just for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the admin sdk updateUser method with user's id to go around this security check. You'll need to either create a firebase function with elevated admin or use REST API directly, but you need to get an admin access_token for that first.

Check this method here:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/blob/master/src/auth/base-auth.ts#L534